# How to maintain different values for every hour of day in week

Tags: mysql

I want to add different rate(cost of hour)  for different hours of day from Monday  to Sunday in a mysql DB table.

I thought of 2 ways

1. creating a column of every day(Week day) so that when I fetch a column I will get entire days rate in one column
2. creating columns for every hour so that I have to fetch based on week day number(1 for Monday 2 for Tuesday). I will get rates of entire day in row

Which is good approach from above 2  or any other good approach for doing this ?
Thanks

Comment: Both approaches outlined above are terrible. danblack's solution (or something like it) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the available MySQL time functions, [WEEKDAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) and [HOUR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) are the easiest way to get to the values you need.

So a table like:

```
 CREATE TABLE rate (day TINYINT NOT NULL,
                    hour TINYINT NOT NULL,
                    rate FLOAT NOT NULL,
                    PRIMARY KEY (DAY, HOUR))
```

So a query could look like:

```
 SELECT rate
 FROM rate
 WHERE day=WEEKDAY(NOW())
       AND hour >= HOUR(NOW())
 ORDER BY day, hour LIMIT 1
```

This `>=` and `ORDER`/`LIMIT` just allows the table to have gaps of hours.